# Why doesn't the alpha pixel in html canvas blend in with the background color?

Tags: colors, html5-canvas, alphablending

http://jsfiddle.net/jBgqW/

I've painted the background with `fillRect` and `fillStyle` set to `rgb(255,0,0)` but when I iterate through the pixels and set some random color and value of the alpha pixel to `0` everything becomes white. I've assumed that when the pixel is transparent it should blend with the previously painted background color or does it always default to white.

I hope that it's just my wrong way of using the canvas.

Can anyone explain why the background isn't red in this case and how do i use the alpha pixel properly? I would like to know if this has something to do with the alpha premultiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `globalAlpha`, the pixel colors are calculated with the current rgba values and the new values.

However, in this case you're setting the values manually and therefore doing no calculations. You're just setting the rgba values yourself, which means that the alpha channel is not used for calculating but is just altered without further use. The previous color (red) is basically overwritten in a 'brute force' way - instead of `rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)`, it's now just `rgba(128, 53, 82, 0)`. The original red color has simply been thrown away.

As a result, an alpha of `0` represents complete transparency, so you see the colors of the parent element.

This can be confirmed if you change the body background color: http://jsfiddle.net/jBgqW/2/.

Comment: I don't understand how can the red color just simply go away. It's already drawn there, I don't think getting the image data from a canvas location and changing these values affects what has already been drawn. And why doesn't putImageData() just do the alpha calculation itself? You sure of that?

Comment: `putImageData` does not combine colors but rather set them explicity. It's not useless, but it uses alpha for the *parent element color*. If you do want to combine the red and your own, you could do the calculations yourself, because you know the alpha values. For example, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jBgqW/2/ (set alpha to 100 and take this value into account when calculating the amount of green).

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat thread necromancy, but I've just faced this problem and have a solution to it, if not for the original poster then for people like me coming from google.

As noted, putImageData directly replaces pixels rather than alpha blends, but that also means it preserves your alpha data. You can then redraw that image with alpha blending using drawImage.

To give an example, lets says we have a canvas that is 200 by 100 pixels and a 100 by 100 imageData object.

```
// our canvas

var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// our imageData, created in whatever fashion, with alpha as appropriate...
var data = /* ... */

// lets make the right half of our canvas blue
ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.rect(100, 0, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();

// now draw our image data to the left (white) half, pixels are replaced
ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0, 100, 100);

// now the magic, draw the canvas to itself with clipping
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100);
```

Voila. The right half of the image is now your image data blended with the blue background, rendered with hardware assistance.